# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel - Tried all possible solution

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, tls1.2

I'm facing an issue once I want to call HttpWebRequest and the error says: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

The code is as below for HttpWebRequest, and it is working without errors in my workstation [ working without SecurityProtocol code ]

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.xxTestxx.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", "TESTXXXXAPI");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Got error message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

*(Above code was a working fine before a few days on the staging server)*

Then I added below two lines to the code, after we deploy it again, still it's giving same error message:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

None of the above code is working, and we got an error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Kindly note I tried the below also:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
```

Last I tried disabling SSL 3.0 for the IIS server on a staging server, I changed the values in registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols

Added the new SSL 3.0 key as below:

**Client:**
DisabledByDefault 1

**Server:**
Enabled 0

Please help same code was working fine before a few days, I don't know if I need to add extra code, or if the error showed up related to the configuration from the server?

Comment: Don't know if this is the reason, but a `POST` request with `ContentLength = 0` is not valid and might be rejected by server.

Comment: TLS/SSL occurs before the HTTP Request is sent.  So content length is not causing this first error.  SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and should not be used.  So you can use either TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  You may be using TLS 1.3.  So make this change : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

Comment: @jdweng Generally not recommended to set the TLS protocol manually, the framework (.NET 4.5 and above) will negotiate the best available.

Comment: Which version of Windows and which version of .NET are you on? And what about the server?

Comment: Side note: the request, response and stream need to be disposed with `using`

Comment: @jdweng, I have tried with ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13; but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @Charlieface, Version of Windows: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: @Charlieface : Again we disagree.  Some server may still be using obsolete version of SSL/TLS and adding 1.2 or 1.3 will make sure you aren't using a version of SSL/TTL that is not secure.

Comment: @jdweng, a screenshot of SSL test result: https://prnt.sc/43_4ru7TzcDi

Comment: Most likely a different certificate was working on you workstation.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of certificates that can be used.  Then client looks up the certificate names in users stores. Most likely a common certificate is not loaded in both client and server.  Also make sure you are using Net 4.7.2 or later which uses operating system for TLS (not Net).  the encryption modes to support TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are in the latest windows updates.  For windows 7 and above. Windows IIR may not have these updates.

Comment: @jdweng That is what SChannel registry settings on the server are for. you can simply disable it for the whole server

Comment: For SSL/TLS negotiation to take place, the system administrator must prepare the minimum of 2 files.  See section "How Does SSL/TLS Work? What Is An SSL/TLS Handshake?" at https://www.websecurity.digicert.com/security-topics/client-certificates-vs-server-certificates?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Charlieface : But if you are at client you want to make sure the server is secure and not running older versions of SSL/TTL.  You may be running a server from a different company that you do not trust.

Comment: Use Wireshark to diagnose the TLS handshake. Check that there exists at least one cipher of the same name between the Client and Server Hello packets. Windows Server 2012R2 needs specific patches and registry settings to allow TLS 1.2, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Comment: @Charlieface, Thank you for your help! I have checked and there has not found any common cipher between the client and server.

Comment: Then presumably the server has not had recent updates, which would have included newer ciphers as well as TLS1.2